# Uniqueness of a minimum capacity $s-t$ cut

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms, network-flow

**Two vertices $x$ and $y$ form an arc that is part of a minimum capacity $s-t$ cut in a directed graph $G = (V, A)$. Prove that another minimum capacity $s-t$ cut cannot exist in $G$ if it only contains the $y$ vertex as part of its arcs and not the $x$ vertex.**

I am not entirely sure how to approach this proof. I realize that I probably need to cut $G$ into two sections $S^*$ and $S^/$. I was then thinking about using the cut lemma to show that the cardinality of any flow has to be equal to the flow out of a vertex subtracted by the flow into a vertex. But I am not entirely sure how I would apply that to this problem specifically. I was thinking that I may have to treat $G$ as a bipartite graph but that did not lead me to a good conclusion either.

I would be extremely appreciative of any assistance!

Comment: How can anything contain a vertex "as part of its arcs"?

Comment: Sorry I think I may have worded it poorly. I basically meant to say that an arc $y-z$ can exist in this other minimum cut but an arc $x-z$ can not, for any vertex $z$ in this other minimum cut. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: The statement you're trying to prove seems false in that case; consider a graph which is just a long path from $s$ to $t$, along which $x \to y$ is one arc, and set all capacities to $1$. Then there's a minimum cut which is just the arc $x\to y$, and another minimum cut which is just the arc $y \to z$ (whatever the next vertex $z$ is).